I am iterating over a list and testing a condition. How do I return something that indicates which list element matched?
So we have the following function and what it does is it finds the right template that matches within the work image.
How do we get some sort of comparable output that we can then later on use if necessary (e.g. if match was the green template then do something) .
import cv2
    
red_template = cv2.imread('resources/temptest/red_template.png')
yellow_template = cv2.imread('resources/temptest/yellow_template.png')
blue_template = cv2.imread('resources/temptest/blue_template.png')
green_template = cv2.imread('resources/temptest/green_template.png')
work_image = cv2.imread('resources/temptest/work_image.png')
all_templates = [red_template, yellow_template, blue_template, green_template]
    
for template in all_templates:
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(work_image,template,
                               method=cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    threshold = 0.945
    if max_val >= threshold:
        print('found it')
        break
    else:
        print('not found')
        continue

The involved files:
red template, yellow template, blue template, green template, work image
Function result when executed:
not found
not found
not found
found it

So it all works fine and as soon as the for loop reaches the matching iteration we get a positive output.
My question is how do we output an identifier for the template that was a successful match?
I have been going back and forth with this and tried a few different methods like adding a return result or return template but none of these give me a measurable object and usually I end up with the following error when trying to compare the output to one of the templates:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes .

Needs reproducible code and more debugging details

Use your "result" value to find the one that matches best.

just added some reproducible code in the hopes that it clears exactly what i'm asking to find out

in all the matchTemplate questions, people always used bad matching modes. you'll find more on that if you look such questions up. -- do you have any questions regarding the ValueError's message and cause of the exception?

I hoped I made myself very clear when I edited the post to explain what I am trying to achieve but it seems I haven't . The function presented above works as it should and all I am trying to do is get some simple output that tells me which template was found to be a match . That's all .

your function's printed output suggests that the logic works. I don't see where you see a hurdle. are you a programming beginner perhaps, and not familiar with how to design a function to return a value that represents the result that you already printed? if that's the case, your trouble is not, as you suggested, with OpenCV or template matching. you might want to look up the python function called enumerate()

Not sure how my question is still not understood.
I have looked up the 'enumerate()' function and I don't see how that answers my question .
I know that the logic works , I have just said that , the 'print()' function proves that as well.
Perhaps instead of trying to school me into python you might want to attempt to recreate what I just said and see how you get on with it and then come back with a valid answer.
So please take this function and enlighten me, how do you return an output that identifies which template was found to be a match.

enumerate(), return index of matching template, or return None. that's all. don't fight against the help. -- people with enough rep can see the entire edit history of your question. we see what code you posted initially. that strongly suggests that yes you're asking a programming beginner's question. that is okay to do. just be straight about it, don't imply it's an issue with OpenCV or template matching. this site is generally not for private tutoring or such trivial questions. we expect questions that aren't trivial, so if you ask a trivial question, it's on you to make that clear.

Was told to come here and ask for help as this is a professional community, seems that it's more professional at criticizing people's skills than actual helping . I see 1 theoretical answer with no applicability in my code and lots of unrelated comments . Great stuff. I will continue the research on my own , the post can now be closed as it seems no one can provide a simple applicable answer but would rather provide lots of unrelated comments. Regards

theoretical? that was a specific function I told you to use, and specific return statements. all you have to do is think about it and place these things where they belong. -- I have given you the solution. all that noise is either you not (yet?) recognizing that it is the solution, or you do recognize it, but refuse to acknowledge it, and just keep going to squeeze some kind of submission out of me. unfortunately, not an uncommon behavior. that sense of entitlement will continue to disserve you

since you're new, please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre], and also [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]

Your template and image is too simple. Please show a realistic set of images. You should make a mask for your templates and use the mask in the matchTemplate function. Possibly use TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED and find the minimum value. Don't threshold limit it or you will get "not found". Simply find minimum of minimum values from your different colored templates. Christoph can comment or correct further. You cannot use Normalized cross correlation like methods as they always fail for solid colored templates or solid colored regions due to divide by zero unless specifically handled.

I don't see how the complexity of the images is relevant here . this is just a MRE of what I am working on . Why is it so hard for you so called experts to take my code into python , and do what I asked then simply come back with an answer .
Christoph seems to have understood what I am trying to achieve but I supposed he's more preoccupied with criticizing rather than helping . I believe enumerate() might be the solution here , I'm just not 100 % sure how to integrate that in my code.

TM_CCORR_NORMED and other normalized cross correlation variants denominators in the formula divide by the standard deviation of the template and the equal sized area in the image. If either is a solid constant colors, then the std is zero and you get a divide by zero result. So TM_SQDIFF is better as it does not have a divide by zero issue. Also making a mask prevents the background from matching or mismatching and thus giving bad matches. Do not be so critical of anyone trying to help with simple comments rather than doing your work for you. That is why they are comments.

All sorted thanks . Reason why it was difficult was due to my inexperience with python, obviously and respectively opencv . I just thought about it wrong all along and was overcomplicating the problem by trying to compare numpy arrays as if they were normal objects and that;'s where I got stuck . I understand the difference between the methods and how to use a mask and I appreciate your further explanations , however with all due respect that was irrelevant to the post like I said .  enumerate() <--- solution

Found a solution by using the enumerate() function.
Code changes as following :
def findtemplate():
    x = None
    for x,template in enumerate(all_templates):
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(work_image, template,
                                   method=cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        threshold = 0.945
        if max_val >= threshold:
            break
        else:
            continue
    return x

Now what the function does is it returns the index of the item that was found in the list.
We can then take that index and get an output that confirms the match :
if findtemplate() == 3:
    print('green image was a match')

Which then results in a succesful print of the green image match .
green image was a match

That is all I wanted to achieve , the ability of mapping each item in the list and getting some sort of index that matches the item so that I could use that later on.
Thanks Christoph for the suggestion !

The enumerate() function simply iterates over a container and returns the index of each item; it doesn't do anything beyond that. Is your issue related to incorrectly retrieving items from a list?

It's a good solution but it wasn't implemented well. Here is my suggestion for the function code.
for index, template in enumerate(all_templates):
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(work_image, template,
                               method=cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    threshold = 0.945
    if max_val >= threshold:
        return index

